# Inbuilt Multi-select JQuery Drop down list

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Are there any inbuilt multiselect drop down lists that comes as a JQuery plugin by default. I tried 3rd party plugins. But my requirement is not such one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout JQuery UI demo http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/ this demo has a multiselect which will work when you press CTRL+Click . On the other hand you require a dropdown. I din find any but a good plugin that I have see http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/ and is highly configurable. Try it out.